Is there an easy way to append values based on column name in Google Sheets API PHP?
I'm trying to add values to Google Sheets via PHP API.
It seems to be easy to add ordered-based values, e.g.
    $updateRow = ['A','B','C'];

    $rows = [$updateRow];
    $valueRange = new \Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
    $valueRange->setValues($rows);
     
    $range = 'Spreadsheet!A1'; 
    $options = ['valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED'];
    $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $options);

What I'm trying to understand is it possible to add values to columns based on their name rather than order?
$updateRow = ['A','Y','Z'];


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand add values to columns based on their name rather than order. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.
